# How can I project X,Y coordinates to the two most distant points in Excel

Tags: excel, projection

I am working with a set of data points collected with a GNSS receiver that are reported in X,Y (northing, Easting) format.  The values in between the most distant points are not always in a straight line but for proper distancing I need to do a little math.  I need to project all of the middle points to the straight line between the two most distant points.  I have been working with a formula.  To help visualize the data, I've attached an image of sample points collected.  Imagine drawing a line segment between the two end points then projecting all other points to that location and creating a new x,y value for the projected point.  That new x,y is ultimately what I'm looking to create.  From there I can compute everything I need.

So does anyone have a suggestion on how to handle this in Excel?  I know it could be done in Python with minimal effort but I want to integrate this into an existing Excel tool with out having to recreate everything.

Thanks ahead of time for any help, thought you have.

```
Point ID,northing,easting
0,1035968.533,2345983.331
1,1035982.422,2345983.331
2,1035994.228,2345982.637
3,1036006.728,2345980.554
4,1036017.839,2345976.387
5,1036037.978,2345977.081
6,1036046.311,2345984.72
7,1036057.422,2345993.054
8,1036069.922,2346001.387
9,1036089.367,2346002.081
10,1036103.256,2346002.081
11,1036116.45,2346012.498
12,1036129.644,2346011.109
13,1036147.006,2346004.165
14,1036158.811,2345998.609
15,1036176.867,2345993.748
16,1036188.672,2345993.054
17,1036205.339,2345990.276
18,1036215.061,2345981.942
19,1036230.339,2345984.72
20,1036240.756,2345995.831
21,1036256.728,2345999.998
22,1036272.006,2346000.692
23,1036285.2,2345993.054
24,1036301.172,2345988.887
25,1036319.922,2345985.415
26,1036331.033,2345979.165
27,1036344.922,2345976.387
28,1036359.506,2345970.831
29,1036372.7,2345956.248
```

[image: Sample graph of X,Y points (unprojected)]

Comment: Can you assume that for practical purposes the two most distant points are the first and last point?

Comment: Absolutely!  Although it would be a normal workflow I use a macro to sort by location.  

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe I or another person will have a look at it. We really need some test data that we can put in without a lot of effort though - it wouldn't be practical to estimate the points from the graph and type them in.

Comment: I added comma separated data with CRLF line ends for all of the points in my sample graph.  I don't see a simple way to attach a csv and inserting tables into my post seems like redundant work for a simple data copy.  With that said, let me know if I can do something to make everything more streamlined.

Comment: What projection method do you want? Eg perpendicular to the joining line?

Comment: You say _I know it could be done in Python with minimal effort_, so you know the algorithm you need.  Describe that in words / math, someone will help you with implementing it in VBA

Comment: Chris, to your first question I am looking for perpendicular projection yes.  To your second comment, I should be more clear that I know it's possible not that I know the exact coding.  I have already reached out to a peer for some example code from a somewhat related project but I have not heard back yet.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a first cut at this - just doing a shift by subtracting the first point from all the points then a rotation using [a standard formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_of_axes)

[image]

where theta (a named range $E$2) is calculated by

```
=ATAN2(C31-C2,B31-B2)
```

where C2 and C31, B31 are the first and last Easting and Northing

and the other two formulas are

```
=G2*COS(Theta)+F2*SIN(Theta)
```

and

```
=-G2*SIN(Theta)+F2*COS(Theta)
```

If the results look on the right lines, this can be tidied up. There is more work to do for the cases where Theta is greater than Pi radians (which means the points are heading south i.e. the final northing is less than the initial northing), or the line is exactly at right angles to the x-axis.

In Excel 365, the whole thing can be done as a spill formula using Let() to calculate the intermediate steps.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you Tom!  I should have some time to work with this today to see the results with a few data sets.  Without doing any testing, this looks like an incredible start and I really can't say thank you enough.

Comment: Tom I was able to play with this just a bit and I think you 100% have be on the right path.  Unfortunately I wasn't able to get to a full processing and modifying but I think I needed another set of eyes to shake me loose from beating my head against my same failed attempts.

Thank you again!

Comment: You're welcome! I'll probably do a bit more on this for my own satisfaction.